# Why can't I create a dropdown list with variables?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with all the values that i have inside my table, but I can't do it, the select box stay blank.

My PHP code, I'm calling a function

Job category

```
<select>
<?php

function category($category_id, $category_name){

echo "<option value='".$category_name."'>".$category_name."</option>";

}

?>
</select>
```

And my function

```
function selectcategory(){
    connect();

    $category = ("SELECT * FROM job_categories");
    $val  = DB_array($category, 'a+');
    $ii   = count($val);
    $ii   = $ii - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $ii; $i++) {
        $category_id = $val[$i]['category_id'];
        $category_name  = $val[$i]['category_name'];
        category($category_id, $category_name);

        }
        }
```

Comment: You need to add some debugging. is `$val` being set? Is your loop running? Also - your `category` function is passed two parameters, but you're using just one of them. I think the first `$category_name` ought to be `$category_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_categories");
  $result = mysql_db_query($dbname, $sql) or die("Failed Query of " . $sql);
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ 

   echo "<option value='".$row["category_id"]."'>".$row["category_name"]."</option>"; // the value should be id

    }
```

Comment: i'm using MVC and i cant put while inside the view

Comment: MVC doesn't prevent you using `while()`!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the flow of your code , that 2nd part executes first , i.e. connection is made , data is fetched and you are calling  **category()** , it will execute

```
function category($category_id, $category_name){

echo "<option value='".$category_name."'>".$category_name."</option>";

}
```

*$ii* times and you are returning to the calling function .

So that's why < select > does not populate the data because it is interpreted *after* running the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php

$result =  category($category_id, $category_name);
foreach($result as $key => $value){
echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```